# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$39.99'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$39.99'`

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with my code?

```
import urllib.request

price = 99.99

while price > 4.74:

    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.shoplavazza.com/products")
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")

    where = text.find('>$')

    start_of_price = where + 1

    end_of_price = start_of_price + 6

    price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])

print("buy")
```

Comment: Don't treat prices as floats. Use Decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do:

```
start_of_price = where + 2    #instead of 1
```

so that the price is `39.99` instead of `$39.99` (which *cannot* be cast as a `float`).

Answer (score 2):

```
where = text.find('>$') # returns the location of >, not the location of $
start_of_price = where + 1 # this is now 1 + the location above, in other words $
end_of_price = start_of_price + 6
text[start_of_price:end_of_price] # Go from $ to 6 characters later.
```

As a note, you'll need to change that 6 to a 5. After all

```
text = 'hello>$39.99'
where = text.find('>$') # 5
start_of_price = where + 2 #starting at character 7, the '3'
end_of_price = start_of_price + 6 # there are only 5 chars after the $
text[start_of_price:end_of_price] # !OH NOS!
```